# Specify autocrlf For git submodule update

Tags: git, git-submodules

When doing a clone, this can be set via:

`git clone https://github.com/project/repo --config core.autocrlf=input`

One would think that the `clone` option of `--recurse-submodules` would inherit from the `--config` value, but it is ignored.

How can a `git submodule update` be run with a defined value for `autocrlf`?

This should be done without modifying the global config setting.

Comment: I don't believe there is an easy one line method for that. You can run an ordinary recursive clone, then use `git submodule foreach` to configure them, then force a new checkout using the new autocrlf setting. But in general I'd recommend avoiding `core.autocrlf` if possible—use `.gitattributes` (per repository and per file) to set things.

Comment: It doesn't have to be one line ;) Would you please post a working solution?

Comment: Mine is untested (I try to avoid submodules) and I know the submodule code has changed a bunch...